# Is it possible to use dynamic weighting (@ConstraintConfiguration) with an EasyScoreCalculator

Tags: optaplanner

I've been reading [the documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.5.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintConfiguration) and it provides some examples for drools and constraint streams, but it doesn't explicitly say whether you can or cannot use Constraint Configuration with an EasyScoreCalculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `ConstrationConfiguration` is a field in the `PlanningSolution` class, it's available in the `EasyScoreCalculator`'s `calculateScore(Solution_ solution)` method, which computes the score of the entire solution for every move.

Let me just note that the `EasyScoreCalculator` does not scale for bigger data sets - exactly because it computes the score of the entire solution for every move.